# Google Map API - Map click event not fired under Polygon, Circle, Rectangle?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, click, event-bubbling

In Google Maps API,
when listening to click events from the Map object,
the event will not be fired when a Polygon, Circle, Rectangle is clicked.

How to bubble up the click event to the Map object?

```
  const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center,
    radius,
    map,
  });

  // This event will not fire when clicking the circle
  map.addListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log('map click');
  })
```

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/rphsf32e/14/ 
Clicking on the map will add a marker. However, if the click is over the circle, the click event will not fire from the map. Only from the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is to make the Circle (and Polygon/Rectangle) "unclickable", set the property: `clickable: false` in the constructor:

```
const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  center: myLatlng,
  radius: 100000,
  map,
  clickable: false
})
```

(or set it using the `.setOptions` method on those objects)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vmwoqc0z/)

[image: screenshot w/ markers after clicking on circle]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  const myLatlng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: myLatlng,
  });
  
  const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: myLatlng,
    radius: 100000,
    map,
    clickable: false
  })
  
  circle.addListener("click", (e) => {
    alert('inside circle');
    console.log(e)
  });

  map.addListener("click", (e) => {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: e.latLng,
        map,
        title: `${ e.latLng.lat() }, ${ e.latLng.lng() }`,
    });
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Click Events</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"
      async
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```